# Trouble with nerdcomment mapping (mapping leader, which maps to itself)

Tags: vimrc

I tried doing the following mapping in [`NERDCommenter`](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter#usage):

```
nnoremap <leader>/ <leader>c<space>
```

However this was not consistently working. I verified the `ttimeout` was a high value, and also I verified that manually pressing `\c` worked. The only way I got it to consistently work is by doing:

```
nnoremap <leader>/ :call NERDComment(1, 'invert')<CR>
```

Why isn't the original mapping working? I suppose it might be because the `nnoremap` does not allow `<leader>` on the `rhs` to re-map to my leader, `\`? If so, what would be the appropriate way to fix this, or is actually calling the function the proper way to do this? (Or should I change this from `nnoremap` to `nmap` ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a *recursive* mapping here, since `<Leader>c<Space>` is itself a mapping, from NERDCommenter.

This should work:

```
nmap <Leader>/ <Leader>c<Space>
```

Plug-ins typically also create `<Plug>` mappings you can use to map your own keybindings to, that's the case with NERDCommenter.

In that case, you can use:

```
nmap <Leader>/ <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
```

This mapping is also valid in Visual mode, so you might also want to define:

```
xmap <Leader>/ <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
```

Here `<Plug>` serves as a "virtual" keystroke, that can't really be triggered by a key combination. Effectively just creating a new namespace for keymaps from plug-ins. It is best practice for plug-ins to define their own set of `<Plug>` macros, to make it easier for users to customize the actual key mappings to trigger specific plug-in features.

The advantage of mapping it to a `<Plug>` mapping is that it then allows you to undefine or redefine the `<Leader>c<Space>` mapping and keep your new `<Leader>/` mapping working.

Comment: thanks again. Given the above, is it ever possible that the function name(spaces) collide across plugins? Or is the function usually called something like [PluginName][FunctionName] ?

Comment: @David542 You mean the mapping `<Leader>c<Space>` or even prefix `<Leader>c`? Yeah it's quite possible other plug-ins try to define the same ones by default... Often, using many plug-ins requires managing the mappings so they won't clash.

Comment: I mean the `<Plug>FunctionNameHere` part, in this case `<Plug>NERDCommenterToggle`.

Comment: @David542 Well those names can be fairly long and plug-ins will typically use their name as prefix. You have the same issue with namespace with global functions or command registered by plug-ins. It's a much lesser issue than keymappings, since keymappings typically *need* to be short, there are only so many keys and Vim itself already takes over most of the keys, so clashes between plug-ins are much more likely there...

Comment: For this mapping: `nnoremap <leader>/ <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle`. It current doesn't work. Do I need to define a `<Plug>` or something in my `vimrc` ? ... Hmm...I. guess in that the non-recursive mode is needed also (is that an issue, I always read about to never ever use a non-recursive mapping?)

Comment: I ended up using the three mappings of: `nmap  <leader>/ <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
vmap  <leader>/ <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle gv
imap <leader>/ <C-O><Plug>NERDCommenterToggle`